# how to use scrapyd start a weekly or monthly task run a spider?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

as the title

Scheduling a monthly or weekly spider run task

and how to use setting params

```
Parameters:
project (string, required) - the project name
spider (string, required) - the spider name
setting (string, optional) - a Scrapy setting to use when running the spider
jobid (string, optional) - a job id used to identify the job, overrides the
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage crontab for scheduling weekly and monthly spiders. Once you deploy your scrapy project in scrapyd, you can simply use this function to make an entry in your crontab using python package:- python-crontab

```
from crontab import CronTab
def set_cron_job(project_name, spider_name, log_path, run_type, hours, minutes, dow, dom, month):
    my_cron = CronTab(user='xyz')
    cmd = 'curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project='+ project_name + ' -d spider='+ spider_name + ' > '+ log_path + ' 2>&1'
    job = my_cron.new(command=cmd)
    if run_type.lower() == "daily":
        job.minute.on(minutes)
        job.hour.on(hours)
    elif run_type.lower() == "weekly":
        job.dow.on(dow)    
        job.minute.on(minutes)
        job.hour.on(hours)
    elif run_type.lower() == "monthly":
        job.dom.on(dom)    
        job.minute.on(minutes)
        job.hour.on(hours)
    elif run_type.lower() == "yearly":
        job.dom.on(dom)
        job.month.on(month)
        job.minute.on(minutes)
        job.hour.on(hours)        
    my_cron.write()
    print my_cron.render()
```